# How to add new lines to XML

Tags: c#, xml

i have this XML-Structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<server xmlns="exampleServer">  
 <system-properties>
  <property name="prop0" value="null"/>
  <property name="prop1" value="true"/>
  <property name="prop2" value="false"/>
 </system-properties>    
</server>
```

but i don't know how to add a new 'property' Line with two Attributes.
Whats the best Way to do this?
I have tried:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(path);
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
string nameSpace = root.GetAttribute("xmlns");    
XmlNode nn = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Attribute, "property", 
nameSpace);

XmlAttribute attr = doc.CreateAttribute("name");
attr.Value = "prop3";
nn.AppendChild(attr);
attr = doc.CreateAttribute("value");
attr.Value = "value3";
nn.AppendChild(attr);
doc.AppendChild(nn);
doc.Save(path);
```

But the Error 'The Node has a wrong type' appears.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception you are running into is caused by the fact you specify `XmlNodeType.Attribute`. What you really want is `XmlNodeType.Element`.

However, if you use [`XmlDocument.CreateElement(String, String)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.createelement?view=net-6.0#system-xml-xmldocument-createelement(system-string-system-string)) instead, you'll get an `XmlElement` object which has methods to make it easier to add attributes:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(path);

// Create the new XML element and set attributes
string defaultNameSpace = doc.DocumentElement.GetAttribute("xmlns");    
var propertyElement = doc.CreateElement("property", defaultNameSpace);
propertyElement.SetAttribute("name", "prop3");
propertyElement.SetAttribute("value", "value3");

// Find the element to append the new element to
var nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsMgr.AddNamespace("ns", defaultNameSpace);
var sysPropNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//ns:system-properties", nsMgr);

sysPropNode.AppendChild(propertyElement);
doc.Save(path);
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/m9wfq8) for an example.

Comment: THX, works fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use *LINQ to XML* API.

It is available in the .Net Framework since 2007. It is much easier and more powerful.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    const string inputFile = @"e:\Temp\Guest.xml";
    const string outputFile = @"e:\Temp\Guest_new.xml";

    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(inputFile);
    XNamespace ns = xdoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

    xdoc.Descendants(ns + "system-properties").FirstOrDefault()
        .Add(new XElement(ns + "property",
                 new XAttribute("name", "prop3"),
                 new XAttribute("value", "true")));

    xdoc.Save(outputFile);
}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<server xmlns="exampleServer">
  <system-properties>
    <property name="prop0" value="null" />
    <property name="prop1" value="true" />
    <property name="prop2" value="false" />
    <property name="prop3" value="true" />
  </system-properties>
</server>
```